# Prove that G is cyclic if normal subgroup is of order 2

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $|G|=2q$ for $q\geq3$ and $q$ is prime, and it has a normal subgroup of order $2$. Prove that $G$ is cyclic.

Here is what I did:

Let $D$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $|D|=2$, $D=\{e,a\}$ for some $a$. I found a quotient group of $|G/D|=q$. This implies that $G/D$ is cyclic therefore abelian.

But how does this imply that $G$ is cyclic? Because I know that a quotient group of cyclic is cyclic, but I don't know the other way around.
Please help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you assuming that G is abelian - you don't state this, but have tagged abelian groups - if not the dihedral group of order $2q$ is a counterexample.

Comment: i didnt mean to state G as abelian, apologies!!

Comment: @MarkBennet What is the normal order 2 subgroup of the dihedral group?

Comment: @MarkBennet:  How is the dihedral group of order $2q$ a counterexample?  I don't see any normal subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: @Phira:  Snap!  I expect Mark misread the question, as I originally did, as being about a normal subgroup of _index_ $2$.

Comment: @Phira Indeed. My folly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a generator $g$ of $G/D$ and look at the order of $g$ and $ga$ in $G$.

Comment: if ga=ag then |ga|=|g|*|a| (then im done), but how do i know if ga=ag since normal means gag^-1 is not equal a.

Comment: Normal means that $gag^{-1}$ is in $D$. You can easily check that it has to be $a$ after all. Your first sentence is not entirely true, it is only true provided the orders are coprime.

Comment: yes yes |ga|=|g||a| only if gcd(|a|,|g|)=1 i forgot to mention it!

Answer (score 0):

Since $H=\langle 1,y\rangle$ of order $2$ is normal, let $g\in G\setminus H$ be any element, then $\mathrm{ord}(gyg^{-1})=2$. Hence it is $y$, so the group $G$ is abelian, hence it is cyclic.

Comment: I may be missing something, but as far as I can see, this only shows that every element of $G$ commutes with $y$, which isn't by itself enough to show that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: but do i need to show that G is abelian, once im done finding the |ga|=|G| using the fact that |gyg^-1|=2?

Comment: @d13:  No, you don't, but that's what you get from Phira's answer, not this one.  I guess if I were you I would accept Phira's answer rather than this one, since this one seems to contain incorrect reasoning.

Comment: @TaraB, what is the incorrect reasoning?

Comment: @math-123:  Going directly from $gyg^{-1} = y$ for all $g\in G\setminus H$ to '$G$ is abelian'.  It would have been more accurate for me to say there is a gap in the reasoning rather than that it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is abelian then you are done, because there are $x,y\in G$ of order respectively $2$, $q$ (Cauchy), and hence $xy$ has order $2q$. If $G$ isn't abelian, then it must be centerless, as otherwise $G/Z(G)$ would be cyclic and hence $G$ would be abelian. But if $G$ is centerless, then it cannot contain a normal subgroup of order $2$, as this latter must be union of conjugacy classes.